# AJAX Form, with php validation through JSON response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a form with required fields which check via PHP. Which generates response in JSON and delivers it via ajax response, in following form
Object {first_name: true, e_mail: false, phone_number: true, themessage: true}

the input fields in the form have the ID which is equal to key of object array.

What I am trying to achieve is to loop through this object array, determine which of the fields is missing and add error message here is how I am doing it.

```
                if (fields_list) {
                console.log(fields_list);
                for (var key in fields_list) {
                    var item = fields_list[key];
                    if (item === true) {
                        $('#' + key).after('<div class=' + key + '>' + data.field_msg + '</div>');
                    } else {
                        $("div" + '#' + key).remove();
                    };
                }; // Loop through fields_list
            }; // if field list exist
```

When doing first form submision it gives me the result which I expect, it adds the div container with error message and with id of the input field after the input field itself. The problem ocurs after second submit if data has been entered into the field, I want that div container after input field to be removed. Instead it keeps appending the div container after field which still submitted without data but doesn't append additional div container to field that has data. How to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having 1 errors div at the top / bottom of your form? That's what we use here for our projects. If you're interested in trying it, you don't have to append a div each time but instead have a div with class "errors" or something be there already, but hidden with CSS. When you get a response, add a flag "errors" in your JSON so that you know wether or not there were errors, and show that div if there were. Then you can add a simple list of the errors with ul's and li's in that div, and clear it each time you submit so you can generate a new list in there if needed a second time.

Comment: I want to create a pointer to each field that has been required and hasnt been field. I now how to do it with one field by toggling the class. But this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Then it would be a case of giving your error fields a certain ID you can check for existence before making a new one. errors-firstName for example, things that correspond with your field keys. Always check for existence and if there is one, update it instead of adding a new one.

Comment: how to check for it existence?

Comment: Could go as simple as if($("#error-" + name).length == 0) {
  //it doesn't exist
}.

Answer (score 0):

the message divs don't have an id. Because of that, your second selector does not match.

the easiest solution if you want to stay close to your existing code is to give those divs an id, too. For example:

```
for (var key in fields_list) {
   $('#message' + key).remove(); //clear old messages
   var item = fields_list[key];
   if (item === true) {
       // add message div with unique id
       $('#' + key).after('<div class=' + key + ' id="message' + key + '">' + data.field_msg + '</div>');
    }
}; // Loop through fields_list
```

Comment: I have mistakently placed class= instead of id " $('#' + key).after('<div id=' + key + '>' + data.field_msg + '</div>'); " as I requested to remove div with id rather than the class. Now it removes unwanted messages but keeps appending error data over input on each submit if data is still missing. I need to append it once instead of multiple times so that it create only one new div tag rather then adding them over and over again on each submit

Comment: if you remove all error divs before appending the new ones, only one per field should be shown. As shown in my code example, I suggest to take the .remove() call out of the else case and execute it for all fields

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fields_list) {
    for (var key in fields_list) {
        var item = fields_list[key];
        $("div" + '#' + key).remove(); // clear old messages
        if (item === true) {
            $('#' + key).after('<div id=' + key + '>' + data.field_msg + '</div>');
        } else {
            $("div" + '#' + key).remove();
        };
    }; // Loop through fields_list
}; // if field list exist
```

cypherabe you really helped.